# Filtering data on Titanic dataset

Tags: python, dataset, filtering

I am using the Titanic dataset to make some filters on the data. I need to find the most youngest passengers who didn't survived. I have got this result by now:

```
df_kids = df[(df["Survived"] == 0)][["Age","Name","Sex"]].sort_values("Age").head(10)
df_kids
```

Now I need to say how many of them are male and how female. I have tried a loop but it's giving me zero for both lists all the time. I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
list_m = list()
list_f = list()

for i in df_kids:
    if [["Sex"] == "male"]:
        list_m.append(i)
    else:
        list_f.append(i)
len(list_m)
len(list_f)
```

Could you help me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: df_kid.groupby('Sex').count() is not working ?

Comment: We didn't review the groupby yet ;( But i will try it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a masking. For example:

```
male_mask = df_kids['Sex' == 'male']
```

And use it:

```py
male = df_kids[male_mask]
female = df_kids[~male_mask]  # Assuming Sex is either male or female
```

You can use the `shape` attribute now if you are interested on counts only.

```py
print(male.shape[0])
print(female.shape[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This worked and makes sense... pandas is hard! ;(

Comment: It's not difficult, it's just matter of time, the more you keep using it, the easier it starts becoming.